# Is using a variable in the environment file in systemd allowed?

Tags: linux, systemd, variable

Is using a variable in the environment file in systemd allowed?

```
[Unit]
Description=ServiceAuto
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/auto.service.d/env.conf
Type=simple
ExecStart="Script to execute"
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
RestartSec=8
TimeoutStartSec=10
TimeoutStopSec=15
User=support

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to know if using variable MAIN_HOME in /etc/systemd/system/auto.service.d/env.conf allowed. For example:

```
MAIN_HOME=/opt/prod
USER=support
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/support/.local/bin:/home/support/bin

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/$MAIN_HOME/bin:/usr/lib
```

Answer (score 5):

From the `systemd.exec(5)` man page:

> ```
>    EnvironmentFile=
>        Similar to Environment= but reads the environment variables from a
>        text file. [...]
> ```

...

> ```
>    Environment=
>        [...] Variable expansion is not performed
>        inside the strings, however, specifier expansion is possible. The $
>        character has no special meaning. [...]
> ```

So, no.